# discord.py bot detecting username changes

Tags: discord, discord.py

trying to make a small bot for my server. it kinda works but if the user removes the nickname, the bot returns a None value. how can i fix this?

the goal is to have a bot detect if a user has TBU in the nickname or username, if it does, add him to a role in discord (havnt added this yet, need to look into it) but if the change removes TBU in the name, remove the role.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.nick != after.nick:  # to only run on status
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Changed nick")
        embed.add_field(name='User', value=before.mention)
        embed.add_field(name='Before', value=before.nick)
        embed.add_field(name='After', value=after.nick)
        # send to admin or channel you choose
        channel = client.get_channel(526517582963146762)  # notification channel
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        admin = client.get_user(174749290902716417)  # admin to notify
        await admin.send(embed=embed)

        if "TBU" in after.nick:
            admin = client.get_user(174749290902716417)  # admin to notify
            await admin.send(embed=embed)
            
        if "TBU" in before.nick and not "TBU" in after.nick:
            admin = client.get_user(174749290902716417)  # admin to notify
            await admin.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You could change `nick` into `display_name`, which supports both a change in nickname and a change in name. You can find this [in the docs linked](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#user)

Comment: Thanks that worked! Changed from None to @user which was less code for setting the variable to that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user has no nickname [nick](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.nick) returns None.

Change `if before.nick != after.nick` to `if before.nick != after.nick and after.nick is not None`, this should work.

Comment: If the person has a nick then removes it, the rest of the code won't work. It needs to know that the nick changed to remove from the role.

Comment: You need to check if the nickname has "TBU" even if the nickname has reset? In that case you should use ```display_name``` instead of ```nick```.

Comment: Glad to help :D remember to accept my answer with the green mark if i been the most useful